# What is the correct method to make a commonly repeated project name stand out?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I have a project titled "Around the World."

I refer to this project often in text. I have been instructed not to use quotes, but I am unsure of the best way to identify this phrase as the project name without quotes.

sample:

> The aim of the ‘Around the World’ exercise as detailed in section 4.2.2.

Should I use italic, or hyphens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the alternative to "double quotes" for signifying a title is to simply use *italics*. Titles can be underlined when handwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a defined term.  So earlier in the work, you would use a long name, then later you can use a short name.

So....
Our students are participating in a year-long study of different countries, the "Around the World Project."

In the Around the World Project, students will do x, y, and z.